# Get date from datepicker and display it in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get the date from the datepicker in jQuery UI and then display the date selected by the user somewhere on the page. The selected date already displays inside the input field of the datepicker, which is great, but i also want to display that exact same value elsewhere on the page inside a div tag.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple. What have you tried? Post your code please.

Comment: I've not hand-written any code myself, however i have recycled code used by others for the past 3 hours to no avail. I can't post all of the different methods i've tried, however i have tried storing the value in the input to a variable and then displaying that variable. I used (rightly or wrongly) `.val()` to get the value, but it never returns anything.

Comment: Post the last thing you tried. Your HTML and JavaScript please.

Comment: If you're stuck, don't forget to go right to the source and check out the API which exposes a method called [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onchange="showDate(this)"` to your input with the date picker.

```
function showDate(input){
$('#div').html(input.value);
}
```

Your div will have the date selected by the datepicker.

Answer (score 4):

Jquery UI actually exposes this functionality for you and will even return a bonafide `date` type.

Just call [`.datepicker("getDate")`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Also, Unobtrusive JavaScript would usually prefer that you not add javascript inline to your HTML.  Instead, you can attach a listener to your datepicker with the `change` event handler

JavaScript:

```
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
    var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    $("#placeholder").text(date);
});
```

### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/SXmZ3/)

Answer (score 2):

onSelect called when the date picker is selected. This code also permit to change the format date to show up in a different div.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function () {
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("M yy", $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        //alert(date);
        $("#month").text(selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <body>
  Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
  <div id="displayDate"></div>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('#displayDate').html(selected);
    });
});

</script>

enter code here


</body>
</html>
```